# MUITableHead color overriden by palette.text.color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a different color for `TableHead` cells and `TableBody` cells. I have added the custom theme for both but the `TableHead` colors are being overridden by the `palette.text.color`.

How can I fix this?

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    text: {
      primary: "green"
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiTableHead: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-northcutt-nbstkr

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to override `color` of the table header cells from the `theme`, try override styles on `MuiTableCell` instead of on `MuiTableHead`.

There is a `head` property under `MuiTableCell` for attaching any styles to the cells on header.

Tested on forked demo here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-david-jsyrih?file=/index.tsx)

Example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    text: {
      primary: "green"
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      styleOverrides: {
        head: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```